# using api with http.client to parse imdb movies database

Tags: python, http.client

I'm trying to retrieve JSON data from this website:
www.themoviedb.org
I can only use the http.client and json as libraries.
I have a valid API KEY that I don't want to disclose in this question.

```
url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=xxxx"
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url,port=80)
## things work well until i call request
conn.request("GET","/")
```

**Error**:

> `for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)`:
>       socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Somehow I think you're missing some code here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When called https site, use HTTPSConnection instead. Also you parse the url incorrectly. This is my non tested example. Tell me if it's failed.

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.themoviedb.org")
conn.request("GET", "/3/movie/550?api_key=xxxx")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.status, r1.reason)
if r1.status == 200:
    data1 = r1.read()
```

Comment: I tried the code and looks like it's working for me.